# Same link creates duplicates in location history

Tags: javascript, browser-history

In Chrome, If you click the same link many times, all of them will be added to browser location history. Navigating back breaks the navigation logic because it navigates through duplicated locations.
if you clicked the same link 3 times then you have to click back button 3 times to navigate the last page

I capture the count of the clicks and I put that count in history.go(-count) but it got  failed in some cases

```
 if(this.page === 'page-link'){
  this.count++;
}
```

note : iam passing this count value through redux

Another file:

```
let counts = this.count;
history.go(-(counts));
```

I am expecting that if I have click same link many times, but  when I click on the back button it should navigate to the last page

Comment: The history works like a stack - if you load the same page multiple times, it gets added to the history multiple times. IF you want to avoid that - do not click on the same link multiple times but use CTRL+F5 to reload the same page.

Comment: I know that thing to avoid clicking multiple times on the same link but the user can't understand

Comment: Okay, tell the user that it is like building a tower from plates - if you put 3 plates on top of each other, even if they are all blue and have the same title printed on them, there are still **3** plates on the tower and you have to pull/remove all the 3 before you return to the original empty table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep pointer event non for particular button when that page is opened.so that the page is not count when tap second time on the same button